# size of rows in ListView in android

Tags: android, listview

Here is my custom list adapter's getView() method

```
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_row, null, false);
        }
        TextView textName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textName);
        textName.Text = mItems[position];
        return row;
    }
```

And here is my listview_row.xml file which is layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<TextView
    android:text="Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textName"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am curious about how list view sizes each row.

When I inflate the "listview_row" into a view and put it in the ListView, I am expecting that the first inflated view will take up whole space of ListView because this view has attributes of layout_width="match_parent" and layout_height="match_parent".

However, when i run this code, each row of the listView size is based on the row's content in the textView. How is it possible? is it something to do with the parameters of inflate() method?

Could you guys explain how ListView sizes its row?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this way to program row list for adapter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="ADD_ROW_HEIGHT"
>
<TextView
    android:text="Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/textName"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I just want to know how listView renders its rows and adjusts rows' height

Answer (score 0):

I think you can consider **ListView** as an area that allows other views to be displayed within it, it's a container. In your case having the view (the **TextView**) as `wrap_content` is saying only take up as much space (vertically) as needed. As such, the **ListView** can possibly hold more than one.

If it's the actual calculations that you want to know, then although I recall seeing something, I can't recall when or where I saw that info.